# Odoo KeyError: 'socket'

Tags: sockets, nginx, odoo

I'm trying to add a couple of workers to the odoo.conf file and once I did that I got the following issue.

```
  File "/opt/odoo/addons/bus/websocket.py", line 817, in open_connection
    Websocket(request.httprequest.environ['socket'], request.session),
KeyError: 'socket'


[options]
db_host = localhost
db_port = 5432
db_user = odoo16
db_password = test123
default_productivity_apps = True
addons_path = /opt/odoo/addons,/opt/custom
logfile = /var/log/odoo/odoo.log
proxy_mode = True
workers = 9
limit_memory_hard = 7247757312
limit_memory_soft = 6039797760
limit_request = 8192
limit_time_cpu = 6000
limit_time_real = 12000
```

I was trying to increase the workers in order to use the https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/16.0/queue_job/ application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you haven't added the necessary `queue_job` related configurations to your Odoo config file. To ensure smooth execution of `queue_job`, you need to specify certain settings, including `server_wide_modules` and channels.

In your `odoo.conf` configuration file, you should include the following parameters:

```
[options]
(...)
workers = 9
server_wide_modules = web,queue_job

(...)
[queue_job]
channels = root:2
```

**Here's what these configurations do:**

1. `workers = 9`: Specifies the number of worker processes that Odoo will use to handle incoming requests. Adjust this number based on the available resources on your server.
2. `server_wide_modules = web,queue_job`: Specifies the list of server-wide modules that should be loaded when the Odoo server starts. `web` module is typically necessary for general functionality, and `queue_job` module is needed for queue processing.
3. `[queue_job]` section: Configures the settings for the `queue_job` module.

   - `channels = root:2`: Defines the channels to be used for communication between worker processes. The `root:2` value indicates that the root channel should have a concurrency of 2.
     You can refer to the official documentation for more details on configuring the queue_job module: [GitHub - OCA/queue_job Configuration](https://github.com/OCA/queue/tree/16.0/queue_job#configuration)

It's worth noting that WebSocket functionality, which is used by Odoo for real-time updates, requires additional configuration in your server environment, such as Nginx or Apache. Ensure that WebSocket connections are allowed and properly configured in your reverse proxy settings. If you're using a reverse proxy (e.g., Nginx, Apache), make sure it's correctly set up to handle WebSocket connections, as WebSocket connections use a different protocol and routing mechanism compared to regular HTTP requests.